# Why can't I filter out an element by its id using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Try this in your browser's JavaScript console:

```
$('<p><span id="wow">FooBar</span></p>').filter('#wow')
```

What I get is `[]`. Why is that? Isn't it supposed to filter out the span who's id isn't "wow"?

Answer (score 2):

There's only one element in the jQuery object, and it's the `p`. The `span` just happen to be a child. Then, the p doesn't match your query and filter returns an empty array.
You might want to use find:

```
$('<p><span id="wow">FooBar</span></p>').find('#wow')
```

Comment: Then, the `p` doesn't match your query and `filter` returns an empty array.

Comment: Thanks. Then what's the correct way to find an element by its id? I know `find` can do it, but it ignores the root elements, is there a function that looks both for roots and their descendants?

Comment: @trVoldemort I can only think of `$.find('*').addBack().filter(crit)` or a similar construct. Why do you need that?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Because in my code I will receive a html snippet and I'd like to search for an element, who might appear at root or its descendants.

Comment: @trVoldemort if that's your server, maybe you could add a wrapper element so that the element being found is never the root? It is even surprising your response does not have a fixed form (as in, a grammar).

Comment: @Blender again, any idea why? They seem to be fully compatible.

Comment: @JanDvorak: No clue. The devs just renamed `andSelf` to `addBack`. The pull request doesn't explain much either: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1170

Comment: @JanDvorak: According to jQuery [Documentaion](http://api.jquery.com/end/), it has something to do with jQuery's way of storing requests. The internal model is like a stack, on which you can perform operations like pop (using `end()`) and the term "back" may refer to the *previous object* in the stack. That's my guess.

Comment: @DekDekku: Aha! That's exactly what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

`.filter()` filters the set of matched elements. The only element in your set of elements is a `<p>` tag, which doesn't match your selector.

You want to use `.find()` instead:

```
> $('<p><span id="wow">FooBar</span></p>').find('#wow')
[<span id=​"wow">​FooBar​</span>​]
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter will give you items that match the criteria. I think you mean to use 'not'.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the syntax of the selector in the [documention](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), and the results may be a zero collection too depending if the element is found or not:

> Calling jQuery() (or $()) with an id selector as its argument will
>   return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one
>   DOM element.